# Is there a way to overlay an image on more than one cell?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

Heyo, I'm trying to implement the following image for a website:

[image]

I've thought of how I'm going to structure it in terms of HTML and I've got this so far:

[image]

With the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <h1>TEXT TEXT TEXT COMPANY NAME'S TEXT TEXT</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="..." alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm subscribe-email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the image to be on top of both cells? Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your paragraph in first col-10 below h1. No need for second row  whatsoever in this situation. That is whole point of columns.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <h1>TEXT TEXT TEXT COMPANY NAME'S TEXT TEXT</h1>
            <p>TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="..." alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm subscribe-email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email">
    </div>
</div>
```